# Cors with Laravel 4 and Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4, cors

This is propably something simple and obvious but I can't see where the problem is.  After some research I found that in order to enable CORS in laravel 4 oen should add the following to the filters.php:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
            $statusCode = 204;

            $headers = [
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true'
            ];

            return Response::make(null, $statusCode, $headers);
        }
});


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        return $response;
});
```

So to my mind when one does this in angularjs:

```
app.factory('RestFactory', function ($http) {
  var BASE_URL = 'url_to_the_site';
  return {
    get: function (target) {
      return $http({method: 'GET', url: BASE_URL + target});
    },
    post: function (target, data) {
      return $http.post(BASE_URL + target, data);
    }
  };
});
```

It should work right?  When running Laravel 4 in localhost:8000 at development mode it seems to work.  However when I transfer the Laravel to my site and try accessing the site url all I get is:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

So What am I doing wrong here?  It works on local, the BASE_URL also works when going to the url with a browser so what am I missing here?

Comment: Any luck with this? Got more or less the same problem.

Comment: Also, why do you need to set the headers in both the `::before` and `::after` sections?

Comment: I'm thinking it's because first frontend asks for options and then sends the actual data so CORS has to be enabled for the additional info too.

As for whether I had any luck... well I haven't tried posting again in server environment for a while but if  there is a typo in my php code then the call returns similar errors.

Comment: Actually I got it to work cross-domain as above, think I just had a typo the first time around. Also, I hadn't realised that a 302 response should be headers only.